# How to give values to all the td in table using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, html-table, user-input

I am trying to give values to all the inputbox which is inside td tag.But my code it is giving value to first td only.Here id is dynamically creating via code.

```
<tbody id="gridview-1161-body">
 <tr id="gridview-1161-record-19832230" data-boundview="gridview-1161" data-recordid="19832230" data-recordindex="2" class="x-grid-row x-grid-data-row" tabindex="-1">

#supplier item
<td role="gridcell" class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-headerId-gridcolumn-1154" id="ext-gen2524">
<div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;">
<div class="rp-invalid-cell rp-icon-alert-require-field"></div>xxx/div></td>
#id
<td role="gridcell" class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-headerId-gridcolumn-1156" id="ext-gen2526">
<div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;">
<div class="rp-invalid-cell rp-icon-alert-require-field"></div>yy</div></td>
#cost
<td role="gridcell" class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-headerId-gridcolumn-1157" id="ext-gen2527">
<div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:right;">
<div class="rp-invalid-cell rp-icon-alert-require-field"></div>$15.00</div></td>
#qty to add
<td role="gridcell" class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-headerId-gridcolumn-1158  rp-grid-editable-cell  rp-grid-editable-cell" id="ext-gen2535">
<div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:right;">
<div class="rp-invalid-cell rp-icon-alert-require-field">
</div>&nbsp;</div></td>

<td role="gridcell" class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-headerId-gridcolumn-1158  rp-grid-editable-cell  rp-grid-editable-cell" id="ext-gen2542">
<div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:right;">
<div class="rp-invalid-cell rp-icon-alert-require-field" id="ext-gen2768">
</div>&nbsp;</div></td>

<td role="gridcell" class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-headerId-gridcolumn-1158  rp-grid-editable-cell  rp-grid-editable-cell" id="ext-gen2556">
<div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:right;">
<div class="rp-invalid-cell rp-icon-alert-require-field">
</div>&nbsp;</div></td>

<td role="gridcell" class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-headerId-gridcolumn-1158  rp-grid-editable-cell  rp-grid-editable-cell" id="ext-gen2563">
<div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:right;">
<div class="rp-invalid-cell rp-icon-alert-require-field">
</div>&nbsp;</div></td>
```

inputbox code : every td has this following same inputbox (same id,class name)

```
<input id="numberfield-1243-inputEl" type="text" role="spinbutton" name="Quantity" class="x-form-field x-form-text x-form-focus x-field-form-focus x-field-default-form-focus" autocomplete="off" style="width: 100%;">
```

Python code:

```
#add qty
for count in range(items_tot):   
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td.x-grid-cell.x-grid-td.rp-grid-editable-cell[role='gridcell']")))
    element.click()


    #input box to give qty-working for this id
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "numberfield-1243-inputEl").send_keys('10')
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "numberfield-1243-inputEl").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: please anybody help me to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

first you need to find all input element.

by using "driver.findElements" functions

and do action like this.

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table//tr//td//input') #xpath to find input

for element in elements:
    element.send_keys('10')
    element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: In my case there are many td,using your code it is not working